# jQuery EasyDropDown tweak to ignore a specific <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery EasyDropDown (http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/b/44474/demo.html) to style the generic select boxes. However, I would like to go a step ahead and tweak the script so that while it's constructing the styled dropdown. All I want to do is ignore a specific `<option>` with class "hidden" when it renders a styled unordered list.

For e.g.

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option>Selection one</option>
    <option class="hidden">Selection two</option>
    <option>Selection three</option>
</select>
```

to render out.

```
<ul>
    <li>Selection one</li>
    <li>Selection three</li>
</ul>
```

Ignoring the second `<option>`

Thanks very much.

Comment: Open the jquery.easydropdown.js file in the src folder and change the following line self.$options = self.$select.find('option'); to self.$options = self.$select.find('option').not('.hidden');

The line is located at line number 37. Now use the src file instead of the min.js file in your page and it should work

Comment: Thanks so much Tonny. I was trying self.$options = self.$select.find("option:not('.hidden')" instead. I see where I had been a fool. :) Have a good day

Comment: Your method would've worked too if you got the syntax right :)

self.$options = self.$select.find('option:not(.hidden)');

But i find the .not('.hidden') more readable